# replace WCF built-in JavascriptSerializer with Newtonsoft Json.Net json serializer

Tags: .net, json, wcf, serialization, json.net

Is there any way to replace the WCF service application built-in JavascriptSerializer with Newtonsoft Json.Net json serializer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WCF doesn't use `JavascriptSerializer`. It uses [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). And yes, you can replace it with Json.NET by writing a [custom message formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.aspx) as exemplified in the [following blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190126174548/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/02/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/).

Comment: because DataContractJsonSerializer is much slower than Json.NET.

Comment: Is this a question that you are asking? Is there something else you would like to ask?

Comment: ok, the question is going further now. According to this article - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a, I have made a custom DispatchFormatter, but how to register it to the wcf service application via web.config?

Comment: You could write a custom `IServiceBehavior` to apply the message formatter globally to the service.

Comment: By following this article - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082231/custom-behavior-wont-register-in-my-web-config), all works now, thank u guys for help.