# Skipping Null values for an object which is a DataMember of DataContract class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a situation where in my slides object is inside a `DataContract` Class `PresentationObject`. The slide Class has its own `Properties`. I want to skip all `Properties` which has `null` values in it.

```
public class PresentationObject
{
    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public string source { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string pdf { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<Slides> slides { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public bool success { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string error_code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string error_message { get; set; }
}


public class Slides
{
        [JsonProperty(Order = -4)]
        public int slideIndex { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = -3)]
        public List<TextResponseJson> texts { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = -2)]
        public List<MediaResponseJson> images { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = -1)]
        public List<MediaResponseJson> preview_png { get; set; }
}
```

I have set `EmitDefaultValue = false` to slides `DataMember` in `PresentationObject` Class, but still the `null` properties are retaining. Can anybody please help me out where I can skip all null `Properties` in `slide` Object.

Comment: `EmitDefaultValue = false` for `Reference Type`s makes no sense, because they don't have a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Newtonsoft JSON serializer. Microsoft does. You can make it do this with a [single property](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm), which defaults to the behaviour you want.

The answer to your next question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153628/replace-wcf-built-in-javascriptserializer-with-newtonsoft-json-net-json-serializ).

Comment: Hit the nail on the head. That was what I was looking for. Thx for the help.