# How to return json date from C# DateTime

Tags: c#, json, wcf, datetime, json.net

I'm using Json.NET/newtonsoft and I have the following C# class:

```
public class EntityDefinition
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to return this class in my wcf I'm getting the following JSON:

```
{
  "GetDefinitionResult": {
    "CreatedBy": "Dor",
    "CreatedOn": "/Date(1466428742000+0300)/"
   }
}
```

How can I get the date to be parsed without the "Date(", meaning only the milliseconds or in iso format "yyy-mm-dd"

I tried using the JsonProperty convertor but it still returns the "Date()"

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle json DateTime returned from WCF Data Services (OData)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818719/how-to-handle-json-datetime-returned-from-wcf-data-services-odata)

Comment: [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) is the converter to use for *collection items*.  You want [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm).  But why did you tag this [tag:wcf]?  WCF doesn't use Json.NET, it [uses `DataContractSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153628).

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] for your problem?  Json.NET does not output dates in that format by default, so I think you unknowingly may be using `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Json.NET does *not* return that format. By default it returns the ISO format. You don't need to use any attribute for that.On the other hand, WCF *doesn't* use Json.NET, it uses the very, very old DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is using `DataContractSerializer` by default to serialize/deserialize messages and the mentioned date format is its default format.

If you'd like to change the way your WCF service serialize/deserialize messages, you should replace some things in the service's behavior (mainly `IDispatchMessageFormatter`). However, it's too long to describe here and there's a great tutorial about it [here](http://itq.nl/replacing-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-with-newtonsoft-jsonserializer/)

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Try  `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))` or use CustomDateConverter as explained here in [Parsing JSON DateTime from Newtonsoft's JSON Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668488/parsing-json-datetime-from-newtonsofts-json-serializer?rq=1)

Comment: Json.NET returns the ISO 8601 date format by default for a number of years. The question you linked to is *VERY* old and no longer applies.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.