# Error sending deserialized Json.net object with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I receive a JSON object from a web service. I can successfully deserialize this object with Json.net. But when I want to send this object with my WCF service using data contract serializer, I get a

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
>       Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract 
>       which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 
>       'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.

If I create a clone of this object then I can send it out. But why not with the deserialized Json.net object?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

WCF doesn't use JavascriptSerializer. It uses DataContractJsonSerializer. Replace it with Json.NET by writing a custom message formatter.

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153628/replace-wcf-built-in-javascriptserializer-with-newtonsoft-json-net-json-serializ)