# How to configure endpoint

Tags: wcf, endpointbehavior

I had a WCF Service

My Web.config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"  />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"  name="MyNameSpace.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="crossDomain" contract="MyNameSpace.IMyService"  behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I recently found this code for array parameter from one of the website

```
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace ArraysInQueryStrings
{
public class ArrayInQueryStringWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    WebMessageFormat defaultOutgoingResponseFormat;
    public ArrayInQueryStringWebHttpBehavior()
    {
        this.defaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
    }

    public override WebMessageFormat DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return this.defaultOutgoingResponseFormat;
        }
        set
        {
            this.defaultOutgoingResponseFormat = value;
        }
    }

    protected override QueryStringConverter GetQueryStringConverter(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        return new ArrayQueryStringConverter();
    }
}
}
```

How to use this extended class in the web.config.

It seems to be an Endpoint behaviour but dont know how to use it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I think you might be taking the wrong path.

Comment: My Services are correctly working. I created a function that will accespt array and i got the error but type 'System.String[]' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.  So i found the solution is to update webhtppbehaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add custom behaviors, you need to add your derived behavior as a behavior extension in config file and need to add a new Behavior extension type. Refer to this post - [Custom Behavior won't register in my web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082231/custom-behavior-wont-register-in-my-web-config)

```
 public class ArrayInQueryStringBehaviorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
 public override Type BehaviorType
 {
    get { return typeof(ArrayInQueryStringWebHttpBehavior); 
 }
}

protected override object CreateBehavior()
{
    return new ArrayInQueryStringWebHttpBehavior();
}
}
```

Config file  (you need to specify your assembly name where I have marked square brackets below)

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name=" ArrayInQueryStringWebHttpBehavior " type="[Namespace]. ArrayInQueryStringBehaviorExtension, [Assembly Name], [Assembly Version], [Assembly Culture], PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="arrayInQueryBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
      < ArrayInQueryStringWebHttpBehavior />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
<behaviors>
```

Comment: I already tried this before posting my question but i am not getting it. I had write almost all the code in the question. can you please tell me what addition i need to write based upon my question

Comment: I have mentioned some code above which you can try. Config file <add> key has places where you need to mention namespace and assembly correctly. Let me know if it works for you