# Replaced DataContractJsonSerializer with Newtonsoft JsonSerializer and it is still using DCJS

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, json.net

I have an old project that is serializing TimeSpans like "PT21H", this is happening because DCJS is the default serializer for the project, I assume. I tried to implement the instructions [here](https://jeroenhildering.com/2014/03/21/replacing-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-with-newtonsoft-jsonserializer/). But, when I hit the endpoint it is still returning the object serialized using DCJS with the Timespan looking like "PT21H"I don't want to overload this with all of my code so I will include what I believe is useful but feel free to ask for more information.

**Relevant section of Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
    
  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
    
    
  <system.webServer>
      <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </modules>
  </system.webServer>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="newtonsoftJsonBehavior" type="Test.WcfNewtonsoftJsonSerializer.NewtonsoftJsonBehaviorExtension, Test, Culture=neutral" />
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>

        <behaviors>

            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="restEndPointBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="false" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" faultExceptionEnabled="false" />
                    <newtonsoftJsonBehavior />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>

            <serviceBehaviors>

                <behavior name="restServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>

        </behaviors>


        <services>
            <service name="Test.WebserviceAscent.Webservice" behaviorConfiguration="restServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restEndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="restWebHttpBinding" contract="Test.Web.IWebservice" />
            </service>
        </services>


        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="restWebHttpBinding" contentTypeMapper="Test.WcfNewtonsoftJsonSerializer.NewtonsoftJsonContentTypeMapper, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

    </system.serviceModel>
  </location>
  <runtime>
...
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have included the same files as the example, I even kept the same namespace for them:

[image]
What am I doing wrong?
I looked at a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153628/replace-wcf-built-in-javascriptserializer-with-newtonsoft-json-net-json-serializ), but I couldn't get it to work. Are these solutions simply outdated and there is a better way to do this?

Edit:
Here is my testcode that is having the same problem:
https://github.com/JasonRAndersen00/SerializerTest

Comment: I checked your code, is the content of contentTypeMapper in your binding correct? I suggest you double check the steps, you can check out [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082231/custom-behavior-wont-register-in-my-web-config).

Comment: This is the content of contentTypeMapper:

using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
namespace WcfNewtonsoftJsonSerializer
{
    public class NewtonsoftJsonContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Raw;
        }
    }
}


So my web.config looks right? I will check out the post. Thanks!

Comment: Compare the code here: `contentTypeMapper="WcfNewtonsoftJsonSerializer.NewtonsoftJsonContentTypeMapper, (Project.dll), Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`.

Comment: @lanHuang, I updated the code and I have a repo with a test project here:
https://github.com/JasonRAndersen00/SerializerTest

I am looking at the code you mentioned and I updated it to the following:

`<binding name="restWebHttpBinding" contentTypeMapper="Test.WcfNewtonsoftJsonSerializer.NewtonsoftJsonContentTypeMapper, Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>`
But it still isn't working. Thank you so much for your responses!

Comment: If I understand this line of code, the pseudo code should look like this:
`contentTypeMapper="Namespace.class, app.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" ` Is this right?

Comment: @LanHuang, I think I found my problem. But I just want to make sure I understand what you are trying to help me see. Is there something wrong with this line of code you pointed out?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with my web.config. It is such a newb mistake I am honestly tempted to not say anything.
I was putting the wrong namespaces on the service.

```
<service name="Test.WebserviceAscent.Webservice"
```

Should be

```
<service name="Test.Web.Webservice"
```

Because of this it just wasn't assigning the serializer to my endpoints.